# Sort matrix according to sample id in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a matrix already set and I am trying to sort it in order of sample id and its associated number.

I have sample id's in mixed order from V1-V26 and I want the matrix to be in the order of V1-V26 and not mixed. How can I sort the matrix in R by the first column of sample id's in ascending order?

Update with second code

```
r<-read.table("testbray.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", check.names = FALSE)
i1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", row.names(r)))
j1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", colnames(r)))
y<-r[order(i1), order(j1)]

>

 dput(head(r[, c(1, 3)]))
structure(list(structure(c(16L, 12L, 3L, 17L, 5L, 22L), .Label = c("V1", 
"V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V17", "V18", "V19", 
"V2", "V20", "V21", "V22", "V23", "V24", "V25", "V26", "V27", 
"V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9"), class = "factor"), 
    V20 = c(0.592334495, 0, 0.893728223, 0.625048393, 0.587882307, 
    0.647502904)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

> 

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as screenshots. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: I get your column names as `colnames(r)#
[1] ""   "20"`  which is not the one you showed from `V1`, `V2` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `gtools::mixedsort`

```
m1[mixedsort(row.names(m1)), mixedsort(colnames(m1))]
```

Or another option is to use `base R` by removing the 'V' with `sub` convert to `integer` and order

```
i1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", row.names(m1)))
j1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", colnames(m1)))
m1[order(i1), order(j1)]
```

Comment: Both ways are successfully sorting the row, but not the column. It is assigning numbers to the column and those are sorted but not the V1-V26. I think it may have to do with how I am importing the table? This is my code:                                      r<-read.table("testbray.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", check.names = FALSE)
library(gtools)

x<- r[mixedsort(row.names(r)), mixedsort(colnames(r))]


i1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", row.names(r)))
j1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", colnames(r)))
y<-r[order(i1), order(j1)]

Comment: @twitney Can you please update your post with the `dput` of the small example

Comment: @twhitney can you sshow `dput` of the data to get the structure correctly an your expected output

Comment: sorry I misread your comment...not sure if this is what you are asking for

Comment: @twhitney  Based on the strucutre you showed, it is not having any 'V' in the column name or row name

Comment: @twhitney  Now, it is not the rownames that aree 'V24', ''V20', but it is the first column, and there is no column name for that. So, I guess it is the data structure that is not correcct